# Store Logo Protection - How is this website doing it?

Tags: magento2.2

https://uk.rs-online.com/web/

If you right click the RS logo there is no 'save image as'. I'd like to do the same on my Magento 2.2 site. Is it some js magic? I can't pick up what CMS they're using but it looks like Magento to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the reference website they are not using any image for their logo thats why save image option is not showing. They are basically using font style for their logo.

Although you can manage to disable the **save image** option by adding the following code to your css file:

```
img {pointer-events: none;}
```

This will remove the save image as option from the image menu. If you want to remove this option from particular image then you need to put the class name like below:

```
<img class="logo" src="example.com/img/abc.jpg"/>
```

then the css will be like below:

```
img.logo {pointer-events: none;}
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't see that line in their website though, so assuming it is more complicated than css.

Comment: I think this is the easiest way to disable save image option.  They are not using any image for their logo thats why save image option is not showing. If you check they are using font not any image.

Comment: Ah, I see, they are using a custom font, I thought it was an icon